# How to find a tuple as value on a dictionary and get its key

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I need to get the key by the given tuple `destino` which I have to find in the list transformed into a dictionary:

```
destinos = [("AF10", [("Lima","Peru"), ("San Jose","Costa Rica")]),
    ("AF11", [("San Jose","Costa Rica"), ("Costa de Panama","Panama")])]


destino = ("Lima","Peru")
# could be any given tuple on the destinos list

destinos_dict = dict(destinos)
# destinos converted into a dictionary


for val in destinos_dict.values():
    if val == destino:
        print destinos_dict.key(destino)
    else:
        print "Destino not found"

# always print on the terminal the else statement, I want the if to be printed
```

Answer (score 1):

I corrected a few smaller mistakes in your for loop. Is this what you need?

```
for  (key,val) in destinos_dict.items():
    if destino in val:
        print "'%s' with key '%s' contains '%s'" % (destinos_dict[key], key, destino)
    else:
        print "Destino '%s' not found in '%s' with key '%s'" % (destino, destinos_dict[key],key)
```

Firstly, better to iterate together over the `(key, value)` pairs. Secondly, you are looking for `destino` in `val` instead of the other way. Thirdly, if you find `destino` in `val`, you know that `destinos_dict[key]` will contain it.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the fact that `destino_dict` contains more than one tuple in its values, you have to look if your tuple is `in` the dictionary value, not only look if it's the same value (`==`).

```
for k, v in destinos_dict.items():
    if destino in v:
        print k
    else:
        print "Destino not found"
```

Also you can use `dict.items` and then you only have to return `k` instead of looking up destinos_dict again.

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that val is a list and you need to iterate over it to be able to compare the values. It seems to me that in python 2 instead of `.items()` is `.iteritems()`.

```
for key,val in destinos_dict.items():
    print(val[0])
    if val[0]==destino:
        print(key)
    else:
        print("Destino not found")
```

Comment: and what if the value of `destino` is found in `val[1]`?

Comment: the second element of the list ("San Jose","Costa Rica")